# Does QuickBooks Web Connector support create Bill Payments

Tags: quickbooks, qbxml, qbwc

We are integrating our SaaS with QuickBooks Desktop, but unfortunately unable to find enough info on qbXML. I remember it was there, but now looks like that Intuit obsoleted it.

- Does QuickBooks Web Connector support create Bill Payments?
- Is it now possible to find comprehensive info on qbXML?
- Is there any other modern ways (besides QBWC) to integrate SaaS with QuickBooks Desktop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, BillPaymentCheck or BillPaymentCreditCard.

See http://developer-static.intuit.com/qbsdk-current/common/newosr/index.html

Answer (score 0):

I think QBWC is the only way you can integrate to QB Desktop -- unless your client uses QB Online in which case you can use a wrapper like: https://github.com/mcohen01/node-quickbooks
for node.js. The closest thing for Desktop is using Web Connector via something like:
https://github.com/johnballantyne/qbws
(example web service for QBWC on node.js using SOAP)